# Visual Studio Code: unable to edit keybingings.json "Cannot edit in read-only editor"

Tags: visual-studio-code

- How to make `keybindings.json` read+write, on Linux Ubuntu 18.04?
- Relatedly,  where is this file located?

My end goal is to remap the `Esc` key.

Comment: just modify the file permissions https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/modify-file-permissions-with-chmod/

Comment: Yes, but what is the absolute path of `keybindings.json`? Edited the question

Comment: If you click on the "{ }" symbol in the top right corner of the keyboard shortcut preferences window, it should open the keybindings.json file in vs code. That way you can see the path of the file and edit the file permissions

Comment: Thank you @SinOfficial!

Comment: Just adding my 2 cents: in the VSCode I run (latest stable version as of today), the symbol is no longer "{}". Now, the symbol is a small "sheet of paper" with the left-right corner flipped and a small arrow in the left side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can open the keybindings.json file by clicking on the "{ }" symbol in the top right corner of the keyboard shortcut preferences window. That way you can see the path of the file and edit the file permissions.
[image: button to open keybindings.json]

Than you can see the path on the top left of the file and edit the file permissions.
[image: path]

Comment: You shouldn't change the permissions, but open the _user_ keybindings.json and edit that instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873895/vscode-show-keyboard-shortcuts-and-user-keybindings-json-side-by-side-by-defau

Comment: VSCode 1.53.0 does not have this option and does not even show path on Kubuntu 20.04.