# VSCode - Show Keyboard Shortcuts and user keybindings.json side-by-side by default

Tags: visual-studio-code

If we set the following two lines in `settings.json` -

```
"workbench.settings.editor": "json",
"workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,
```

We get split screen with json. So when we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Comma</kbd> we get -

[image: settings split screen]

Is there any settings to get split screen where `Keyboard Shortcuts` and `keybingings.json` resides side-by-side using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. something like the following -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a setting to do this automatically.  But you could set up a macro to do it pretty easily.

Using a macro extension, here [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this into your settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.openSplitKeybindings",
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.openGlobalKeybindings",
      "workbench.action.newGroupRight",
      "workbench.action.openGlobalKeybindingsFile",
    ]
  }
]
```

and then in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+s",                 // remove the default keybinding
  "command": "-workbench.action.openGlobalKeybindings"
},
{ 
  "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+s",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.openSplitKeybindings" },
}
```

I removed the default keybinding above but you could just keep it and choose a new keybinding for the macro if you wish.

### [image: keybindings split demo]

The gif doesn't show it well but I used the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keybinding to trigger the macro and it is faster and smoother than it appears in the gif.

You cannot just click on the Gear Icon/Keyboard Shortcuts to get this behaviour - I don't think you can change the Gear Icon/Keyboard Shortcuts default action - especially since it doesn't present a shortcut binding in the menu there.  But you stated you were looking for keybinding solution.